# Excel VBA how to use index when we have more if then else function

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code with more then 50 lines of If Then ElseIf function. When I run macro, it will satisfy one "if" condition. If the data meet, 50th Elseif condition, then macro will go through unto 49 if condition. I know, one basic value that meet the condition. Since I am able to find value that meet condition, Can I directly jump into that particular if Condition? Any help would be much appreciated

```
If A=10 and B=39 then
Do Something....
Elseif A=11 and B=30 and C=56 then
Do Something....
Elseif A=13 and B=35 and C=60 then
Do Something....
...
etc
```

Here Since I know A=13, Can I directly jump to

```
Elseif A=13 and B=35 and C=60 then
```

without going through first two if condition?

Comment: Even if you have 200 lines of `If-Then` the code execution to evaluate `If Then` will happen in split second until and unless you have complex conditions. Can you show your code? Maybe it can be optimised?

Comment: If you know that A=13 then why do you need all the Ifs?

Comment: You can use Select Case which will be prettier but computationally equivalent

Comment: @jivko A=13 was a hypothetical example

Comment: @Kelaref 
 
 
Is there anyway where we can use three conditions using case select function?

Comment: @Manish Select Case True   Case A = 10 and B = 39

Answer (score 0):

To your question - can you prioritize the 49. `ElseIf` condition - **NO**.

But you can put it in number 1 or 2, if you want to do it faster in debugging. 
Like this:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim a As Long
    a = 5

    If a < 6 Then
        Debug.Print "The most popular"
    ElseIf a = 5 Then
        Debug.Print "The 2. most popular"
    ElseIf a > 2 Then
        Debug.Print "The 3. most popular"
    End If

End Sub
```

As mentioned in the comments, the fact that you would have about 50 small evaluations would not slow your code (unless there is a non optimized function in the evaluations or you are accessing a database there).

Comment: Is there anyway where we can use three conditions using case select function?

Comment: @Manish - `select case true:case a<6:end select`